# Deploying Java app to multiple vm's using SSH with pinhole

Tags: java, git, deployment, ssh, rsync

I have a java app I'm developing on my home machine that is distributed and as a result I need to upload it to N VM's every time I'd like to test.

Unfortunately, these VM's are hosted by my school which requires a user to first ssh into a login server and then ssh into the VM's. As a result, I can't use RSync like I originally planned and am looking for an easy way to essentially mirror my current project using SCP, or automate sshing into my schools login servers then sshing into the vm and finally doing a git pull for several vms.

I've been researching tools and can't find anything that fits my specific situation. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to automate your deployments. It has git SCM polling features and scripting capabilities that should solve the problem.